# FluentValidation errors to Logger

Tags: asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

I'm registering my FluentValidation validators as follows:

```
services.AddFluentValidation(fv => fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<CustomRequestValidator>());
```

How can I get a handle of any validation errors to log them via my logging implementation, e.g. Serilog?

Comment: Did you try https://fluentvalidation.net/aspnet#validator-interceptors?

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

For users stumbling into this problem (like me) I'd like to provide the solution I found.

The actual problem is that ASP.NET Core, and APIs in particular, make [Model State errors automatically trigger a 400 error response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#automatic-http-400-responses), which doesn't log the validation errors.

Below that same documentation they include [instructions on how to enable automatic logging for that feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#log-automatic-400-responses) which I believe should be the correct solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

To jump onto what @mdarefull said, I did the following:

```c#
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Possible other service configurations

    services.AddMvc()
        .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
        {
            options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = context =>
            {
                if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    LogAutomaticBadRequest(context);
                }

                return new BadRequestObjectResult(context.ModelState);
            };
        });

    // Possible other service configurations
}
```

The `LogAutomaticBadRequest` method is as follows:

```c#
private static void LogAutomaticBadRequest(ActionContext context)
{
    // Setup logger from DI - as explained in https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/12157
    var loggerFactory = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
    var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger(context.ActionDescriptor.DisplayName);

    // Get error messages
    var errorMessages = string.Join(" | ", context.ModelState.Values
        .SelectMany(x => x.Errors)
        .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage));

    var request = context.HttpContext.Request;

    // Use whatever logging information you want
    logger.LogError("Automatic Bad Request occurred." +
                    $"{System.Environment.NewLine}Error(s): {errorMessages}" +
                    $"{System.Environment.NewLine}|{request.Method}| Full URL: {request.Path}{request.QueryString}");
}
```